# Error with tokenizing data while reading csv files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Hi I have a lots of csv files, and want to put them into one big df

```
tmp = [] 


for file in directory_liste:
    df_x = pd.read_csv(file)
    tmp.append(df_x)


df = pd.concat(tmp)
```

I got this error

`ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 3`
I have really no Idea how to solf it

here is the full error report

```
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-c8e42d981b3a> in <module>
      3 
      4 for file in directory_liste:
----> 5     df_x = pd.read_csv(file)
      6     tmp.append(df_x)
      7 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    700                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    701 
--> 702         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    703 
    704     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    433 
    434     try:
--> 435         data = parser.read(nrows)
    436     finally:
    437         parser.close()
```

Comment: Does your data in line 3 have an extra comma?

Comment: this problem usually relates to having an issue with the input, so doesn't hurt to look at it to make sure it's well-behaved

Comment: Typically it's caused by issues with extra delimiters, (fields with commas in a comma separated file), that also lack the proper quoting. Perhaps a comma isn't truly the delimiter, might be pipes or tab or something else. You can try to play around with `quoting=3`, otherwise you might manually need to fix the file.

Comment: ` "VarName" ; "TimeString"; "VarValue","Validity ", "Time_ms" ` this is the format. is there maybe one file with a different format ?